# UITableViewCell become nil after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I a UITableView called `tableView`. It's data array called `namesArray`.

I have a function that adds a name to the array that looks like this:

```
-(void)addName:(NSString*)name
{
    [self.namesArray addObject: name];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

After I call `reloadData` on `tableView`, the last cell (the one that was added) is not showing on `tableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection` return the actual number so there is a space for another cell but there is not an actual cell.

I was debugging `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I was found out that when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called for the new cell, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns nil while when it called to the other cells (except when indexPath.row == 0 of course) it returns a cell.

The code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[self.namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

numberOfRows:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.namesArray.count;
}
```

Note: if I try to print the last object of `namesArray` using `NSLog` it's looking fine (the last object is the new one that was created) so it's a problem with reloading the data of `tableView`

Can you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the code in `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: Thats not how you should dequeue cells, you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier:forIndexPath:)` which always returns a valid cell

Comment: @AliRiahipour Yes! I've updated the post

Comment: @DanielGalasko I don't want to register a nib for the cell, I want the default one.

Comment: you can register a class or a NIB. see the API: `registerClass(:forReuseIdentifier)`

Comment: If you add name one by one,  Try to use insertRowsAtIndexPaths to update the tableView.

Comment: @Yhper hi as many people answered here. but you are not getting proper answer. please could you post your .h and. m complete code then it would easy to update your question in less time

Comment: @DanielGalasko still not working...

Comment: @Paruru It's crashing my app...

Comment: @Imran it's alot of code.

Comment: Just a note: if I try to print the last object of `namesArray` using `NSLog` it's looking fine (the last object is the new one that was created) so it's a problem with reloading the data of `tableView`

Comment: i used your exact code, it works fine for me, everytime i press on add button and call the `-(void)addName:(NSString*)name` it reloads the table properly and adds each name below the above name properly.

Comment: @RahulPatel so what can be the problem?

Comment: i posted below what i have written, see if there is anything missing

Answer (score 0):

check the number of rows you returns in numberOfRowsInSection

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

it should be something like:

```
[self.namesArray count];
```

Comment: Updated the post, take a look please

Comment: set breackpoint on the  [self.tableView reloadData]; line and make sure, that  self.tableView is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

First dataSource  and delegate  the tableview. after that make sure using below method with perfection

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
     }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [your array count];
    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (!cell) {
                cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text=[self.namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return cell;
        }
```

After that reload tableView with

```
[_tableViewName reloadData];
```

Comment: Make break point check it brother and delete the outlet and give again with diffrent name of tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)addName:(NSString*)name
{
    [self.namesArray addObject: name];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If you are calling this function again and again to fill the array then, do not reload tableview in this method. Because, its getting reloaded overtime you call this method and cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called every time. So, after your array gets filled completely then, reload the tableview

Comment: The function is being called every time that the user clicking on a button, so it's dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{

IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
IBOutlet UITableView *tableObject;
NSMutableArray *namesArray;
}
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(UIButton *)sender;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return namesArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)addName:(NSString*)name
{
    [namesArray addObject: name];
    [tableObject reloadData];
}
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self addName:txtName.text];
}
```